# Add method to class for each template (int) parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a sequence of numbers which should not be continual. Let's say 5, 2, 3 and I want them to map to array indexes (5 -> 0, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 2). Here is my code which seems to be correct to me.

```
template<size_t Index, int ...Values> 
struct indexer;

template<size_t Index> 
struct indexer<Index> { };

template<size_t Index, int T, int ...Rest>
struct indexer<Index, T, Rest...> :
    public indexer<Index + 1, Rest...>
{
    template<int Value> size_t get();
    template<> size_t get<T>() { return Index; }
};

// this class (should) maps Values... to 0,1,2...
template<int ...Values>
struct mapper :
    public indexer<0, Values...>
{ };
```

Now when I can call:

```
mapper<5, 2, 3> m;
m.get<5>();   // returns 0 as expected
m.get<2>();   // does not compile
```

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned int __thiscall indexer<0,5,2,3>::get<2>(void)" (??$get@$01@?$indexer@$0A@$04$01$02@@QAEIXZ) referenced in function _main    C:...\ATL.Console\main.obj ATL.Console

Can anybody explain what's wrong? Seems that m does not have function get<2>(), but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 does not allow an explicit specialization inside class scope. This declaration:

```
template<int Value> size_t get(); // primary template
template<> size_t get<T>() { return Index; }  // <-- this one
```

is illegal, and only accepted in MSVC++ because of a language extension.

Additionally, it probably does not do what you want:

```
template<int Value> size_t get();
```

This declares a member function template. By declaring a member with a name `get`, you hide all members with the same name declared in any base class.

Then, the explicit specialization:

```
template<> size_t get<T>() { return Index; }
```

says something like (if it were legal): If overload resolution selects the primary template `get` declared the line before, and if the template parameter passed to that member function template is equivalent to the template parameter `T` of the class template, then here's a definition of a function you shall use (instead of the definition of the primary member function template).

An explicit specialization of a function template provides an alternative definition for a function template. It is not a function (template) in its own right, and does not participate (itself) in overload resolution.

Of course, if overload resolution selects this member function template, but the template parameter condition does not hold (= when `value != T`), then the definition of the primary template is used instead. But the primary template does not have a definition! Hence the linker error.

---

Here's how you can do it:

```
#include <cstddef> // for std::size_t
#include <type_traits> // for std::integral_constant

template<size_t Index, int ...Values> 
struct indexer;

template<size_t Index> 
struct indexer<Index>
{
    // provide a dummy to allow simple overloading via a using-declaration
    // if you see a linker error here, then Value could not be found
    template<int Value>
    size_t get(std::integral_constant<int, Value>);
    // it would be nice to provide a definition for the template above,
    // containing a `static_assert` for a nice compile-time error message,
    // but I'm not sure on what to assert.
};

template<size_t Index, int T, int ...Rest>
struct indexer<Index, T, Rest...> :
    public indexer<Index + 1, Rest...>
{
    template<int Value>
    size_t get()
    {
        return get(std::integral_constant<int, Value>());
    }

    // a using-declaration to allow overloading
    using indexer<Index + 1, Rest...>::get;

    size_t get(std::integral_constant<int, T>)
    { return Index; }
};

// this class (should) maps Values... to 0,1,2...
template<int ...Values>
struct mapper :
    public indexer<0, Values...>
{};
```

Of course, now there are many redundant `get(void)` member function templates (all those member functions can be `static`, btw.). So you can move it into `mapper` or even provide a non-member function.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dyp. Just one detail: my compiler required to add **typename** in the using (using **typename** indexer<Index + 1, Rest...>::get). Otherwise I saw _internal error has occurred_

Comment: @vajanko An internal compiler error is always a bug in the compiler (that you should report to the vendor/producer/maintainer). A `typename` here would even be illegal in Standard C++, since `indexer<..>::get` is not the name of a type (see [what clang++ says about it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0ecfabe065adbb6)). But well.. if it helps ;) (just be aware that this is a nonportable workaround)